# continuous internet check in background - Android

Tags: java, android

I have written class that checks if there is internet connection, and now i want to check every 1-2 secs if there is internet to close special prompt.

I added class inside activity that extends AsyncTask and do this in this class this is code:

```
public class NoInternet extends Activity {

    private ConnectionDetector cd;
    public Boolean isInternetPresent;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nointernet);

        new RefreshTask().execute();
    }

    public void closeActivity() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }

    class RefreshTask extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            String text = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

            if(isInternetPresent) {
                closeActivity();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            while (!isInternetPresent) {
                try {
                    //sleep for 1s in background...
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    publishProgress();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                };
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And it's not working correctly ... any advices or tips?

Comment: applications freezes and gets closed by system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the wrong way to do this.  First off, if you need something in the background all the time, use a Thread, not an Async Task.  Not only is it a better fit, but using an AsyncTask would break other AsyncTaks, since they execute on a single thread by default.

Secondly, its more efficient in battery and CPU to be notified than to poll.  Use a BroadcastReceiver for http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION rather than polling for the connection status.

Comment: A thread is not persistent, in Android.  You need the Alarm Manager.

Comment: No, a thread is definitely persistent.  How do you think an AsyncTask is written-  it's a thread with a runonUIThread block written for you.  It lasts even after the activity is destroyed.  An AlarmManager is not needed.  Nor is either thread or AlarmManager the right answer here-  he should be using the broadcast receiver.

Comment: No a thread is not persistent.  It gets killed when the process is killed, by Android, because it needs space for other apps.  OP wants to poll: AlarmManager is the way to do that.  Broadcast receiver is a also a good suggestion.

Comment: then i'll check broadcast reciver a try

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike  First off, that's not what he needs-  he needs something to run in the background, not something to run after the app exits.  Secondly, if the app exits then the alarm would also be killed-  the only thing that persists after program exit is a broadcast receiver listed in the manifest.  However a thread will persist as long as the activity/service it was launched in does, and will actually outlast either of those so long as the app itself isn't killed.

Comment: @GabeSechan No.  Apps are killed.  Alarms are not.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike When an app is killed, all broadcasts for it not in the manifest are canceled.  You may be able to specify an alarm in the manifest, I've never tried to.  But unless you can show me a link that specifies that alarms have a special behavior that no other BroadcastReceiver has, I believe you are wrong.  As proof-  I have an app that has an alarm on a 30s timer.  I just checked if it continued to write the log if force stopped.  It didn't.

Comment: @GabeSechan. Alarms have nothing to do with Broadcasts.  You schedule a PendingIntent with the AlarmManager and schedule it for delivery at some interval.  Delivering the intent will restart the app, if necessary.  Watch your program for 30sec.  It will start logging again.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike  Watched for several minutes.  It didn't log again ever.  Not until I manually launched the app, starting the alarm again

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike : "Watch your program for 30sec. It will start logging again.". No it won't or at least not on later versions of Android (v3.1+ if I remember correctly). If an app is force stopped then it is considered to be no longer trusted or wanted by the user and as such nothing will ever work until the user manually starts it again.

Comment: @Squonk Damn you're right.  So it isn't a valid test anyway.  Hmm, how do we test it then-  closing of the activity/service isn't the same as killing the app either.  And my 2.3 devices are about 2000 miles away at the moment.

Comment: @GabeSechan : The issue is effectively moot. The OP's approach to wanting to poll the network connection periodically is misguided. Your approach using a `BroadcastReceiver` is correct in order to receive broadcasts WRT to network connection state. If, however, the app is force stopped who cares that it won't receive broadcasts? It's dead and can't do anything anyway. End of story and that's how it should be. If I force stop an app I don't want it to come back to life unless I tell it to.

Comment: @Squonk What GabeSechan said.  I didn't know that.  Try, however, just killing it with a simple kill -9.  It will restart.

Comment: @Squonk A reason that I am sure of this is that I just wrote the app that the OP describes.  I needed to log connectivity, to a specific endpoint, from my phone, every 10 sec all the time.  Alarm Manager worked like a charm.  ...btw I also agree that if the app only needs to notice changes in connectivity while it is running, BroadcastReceivers are best.

Answer (score 0):

You've given absolutely no indication about how it fails...

Let me guess two possibilities:

1. It blocks all subsequent AsyncTasks.  An AsyncTask submitted with the `execute(...)` method is run to completion before subsequent tasks are started.  Since this one runs forever, it will block subsequent tasks.
2. This task is, eventually, killed.  Android will terminate your process, when it needs space, and your AsyncTask gets stopped.

Have a look at the AlarmManager.  You can use it to schedule repeating tasks.

Comment: to be honest i don't now how it fails ... i guess 2nd option couse applications freezes and gets closed by system

Comment: Not sure why the app would freeze, but it will, most definitely, eventually get closed by the system.  Use the AlarmManager.

Comment: `AlarmManager` is not a good way to trigger code as regularly as 1-2 seconds. Besides, the OP has the wrong idea of what he/she should be doing. Using a `BroadcastReceiver` is the usual way to monitor network connectivity.

Comment: @Squonk fair enough.  If you need persistent notifications, at whatever interval, however, the AlarmManager is the *only* way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this service Class. Just set the time interval in seconds and the url to ping:

[Android Check Internet Connection](https://github.com/oscarjiv91/Android-Check-Internet-Connection)

Just remember to add the service to the Manifest file, and add the permissions